Impulse signal detection
Notation: Here $\mathcal Y_t$ denotes the natural filtration of the process $Y_t$, and $\{\cdot\}$ denotes the fractional part of a real number.
This question concerns detecting the presence (or otherwise) of a brief, periodic impulse signal in the presence of noise.
Let $X$ be a uniform random variable on $[0, 1]$, and $0 < \delta < 1$ a real number. Consider the solution $Y$ to the SDE
$$dY_t = A \, \mathbf 1_{[0, \delta]} (\{t - X\}) \ dt + \sigma \,dW_t,$$
with $W$ a standard one dimensional Brownian motion independent of $X$, and $A, \sigma > 0$ constants. We assume the starting condition $Y_0 = 0$ a.s.
In this setup, $\delta$ is the duration of the impulse signal, $\sigma$ is the strength of the noise, and $A$ is the amplitude of the signal.
Question:
I believe that given enough time, we can ascertain with almost certainty whether or not the signal is present. More precisely, we should have $\mathbb E[X| \mathcal Y_t] \to X$ almost surely and in $L^1$ as $t \to \infty$, but this seems quite difficult to prove.
In any case, if this is true, I would like to quantify the effects of the parameters on the result. Can we estimate $\mathbb E[|\mathbb E[X | \mathcal Y_t] - X|]$ in terms of the parameters $\delta, A, \sigma$?
References: The ideas in the paper Seperating signal from noise  (Liv, Peled, Peres) may be helpful.

As soon as t > 2 $Y_t = A \delta + \sigma W_t$ so I don’t think you get any information about X after that time.

@mike I don’t think that holds, perhaps something in the problem set up is not clear?

I believe explicitly we have $$Y_t = A\delta ([t] - 1)_+  + \max({t}, X) +  \max({t}, X + \delta - 1) - X + \sigma W_t.$$ Which is messier than I expected! Maybe there is a nicer way to write it.

Although I don’t think the explicit formula is of much help anyway to answer the problem.

… sorry typo, it is $$Y_t = A[\delta ([t] - 1)_+ +\max({t}, X) +  \max({t}, X + \delta - 1) - X] + \sigma W_t.$$

I think the drift is always < A and is zero as soon as t > 2.   The expected value of Y can’t be bigger than 2A, whereas you have it being about proportional to t for large t.

Does the following make any sense?
For $n = 1, 2, \ldots$ and $t \in [0, 1)$ let
$$ Z_n(t) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} (Y_{k + t} - Y_k) . $$
Then $Z_n$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal Y_{n + t}$ and
$$ Z_n(t) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \biggl(\sigma W_{k + t} - \sigma W_k + A \int_0^t \mathbb 1_{[0,\delta]}(\{n + s - X\}) ds\biggr) . $$
Since the integral does not depend on $n$, in fact we have
$$ Z_n(t) = \frac{\sigma}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} (W_{k + t} - W_k) + A \int_0^t \mathbb 1_{[0,\delta]}(\{s - X\}) ds . $$
The first term almost surely converges to zero (in fact uniformly with respect to $t \in [0, 1)$). Thus,
$$ Z(t) = \lim_{n \to \infty} Z_n(t) = \int_0^t \mathbb 1_{[0,\delta]}(\{s - X\}) ds $$
is measurable with respect to $\mathcal Y_\infty$.
Knowing $Z(t)$, one easily reconstructs $X$ (e.g. the unique $t$ such that $Z'(t^-) = 0$ and $Z'(t^+) = 1$ is equal to $X$), so it turns out that $X$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal Y_\infty$. In particular, $\mathbb E[X | \mathcal Y_t]$ is a martingale which converges to $\mathbb E[X | \mathcal Y_\infty] = X$ almost surely and in $L^1$.

Hm, I will check this in detail soon, interesting idea.

I assume you meant $W_{k+t} - W_k$ everywhere, so I am modifying it, but please let me know if I am mistaken!

The solution checks out IMO, very nicely done.

Wait a minute, there is still another question open, the one about the rate of convergence. Time permitting, I will get back to it later this week. Oh, and thanks for the edit, that is what I meant.

Yep, you could still answer that if you want. I will unaccept the answer so the problem will display as still open, but enjoy the +500 imaginary points as my show of gratitude!
